# PWA Frontend changes will reflect only after yarn run build

Tags: pwa-studio, venia, react, yarn

In the PWA Venia setup [ **ReactJs** ] , the code changes will reflect in frontend of the website only after we run this command : **Yarn run build** and it ll take 15- 20 seconds to complete.

It will be acceptable in Staging website, but in the Production or live website, it will affect the User experience and there are high chances customers will leave the site.

**Requirement** :

Is there any way, we can see the changes in frontend without running command ?